# recover lost unversioned files after git clean -d -f

Tags: git

I have the feeling the answer to this question is no but I figured I would ask anyways.

Long story short I accidentally did a `git clean -d -f` on a branch and lost about 20 files that I needed. These files have not been committed so as far as I know git shouldn't know about them. Is there any way I can get these files back?

Comment: Were those lost files at least `git add`-ed?

Comment: i thought they were added and committed. I did a git commit -a -m but i guess i was in the wrong branch or missed something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, your only option is a filesystem "undelete" program. For maximum probability of success, don't do **anything** on that volume until you obtain and can use an undelete program (ie. don't even download the undelete program onto that volume).

Comment: I tried rstudio with no success. Oh well I get to make sure that design is what I really wanted :)

Comment: Code is always better the second time. This has happened to me more than twice. :)

Answer (score 1):

I also just lost files. Why the hell git doesn't recycle them, or stick them in its own internal cache, I do not know.

I was able to recover some files with both r-studio and Pendora Recover.

But not the biggest, most complicated one!